# Bessel function integral

Tags: matlab, numeric, symbolic-math, integral

I try to compute the integral of the Bessel function with MATLAB but the result is not correct

```
syms x a
int(besselj(1,a*x)*x^2,0,1)
```

The result is

```
(2*besselj(1, a))/a^2 - besselj(0, a)/a
```

I expected instead `(- besselj(0, a)/a)`.

Why did I get a wrong result? What do I need to do to get the correct integral?

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha the result is `besselj(2,a)/a`: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%28besselj%281%2Ca*x%29*x%5E2%2C0%2C1%29) MATLAB might be giving you a different way of writing the same thing? Ah, yes, indeed, the two forms are equivalent. [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282*besselj%281%2C+a%29%29%2Fa%5E2+-+besselj%280%2C+a%29%2Fa). So it is your expectation that is wrong, it seems.

Comment: To investigate whether the integral is correct, you can try computing numerical approximations (via whatever quadrature function is provided -- I don't remember what it's called), and see if the result matches your expected result for specific values of the free parameter (namely `a` here).

Comment: hello, thank you very much I found the solution.
MATLAB does not know that a_k is the root of besselj(0,a_k). i.e. besselj(0,a_k)=0 for k=1,2,3......  
So I have to eliminate besselj(0,a_k) from our final calculation in MATLAB.